# Adding autofocus attribute when input is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add autofocus to an input form when it's hovered.

Using the .appentTo attribute but open to other solutions.

Here's what I have:

```
<input value=""/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").hover(function(){
        $("autofocus").appendTo("input");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7yj3b4n/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To focus an element use `focus()` method. Here you try to add the attribute `autofocus` with a bad method (take a look at Zakaria's answer) to all input. Use `$(this)`for target the hovered element

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").hover(function(){
       $(this).focus();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value=""/><input value=""/><input value=""/>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Alexis. Will accept in 10mins once the limit has passed. Is there a way to toggle the focus?

Comment: What do you mean  by toggle the focus ?

Comment: When the cursor is not on the input the focus is removed.

Comment: Yes with `blur()` method

Answer (score 3):

To add attribute to element you should use `.attr()` or `.prop()` and not `appendTo` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").hover(function(){
     $(this).prop('autofocus');
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** The `autofocus` attribute will not make the input focused but `focus()` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, i don't know what is the OP real intention.

Comment: @Alexis it looks like he search really for a focus :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").hover(function(){
        $(this).focus();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7yj3b4n/2/

Answer (score 0):

You must use .focus();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").hover(function(){
        $(this).focus();
        });
});
```